# Evaluating an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find the value of this sum.

$$\left(\frac{b}{1-ab}\right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(c+ (n+1)I\right)^d\left(\frac{ab}{1-ab}\right)^n $$

My thoughts:
Writing out the first terms

$$S = \frac{b}{1-ab}\left[ (C+I)^d + (C+2I)^d\frac{ab}{1-ab} + (C+3I)^d\left(\frac{ab}{1-ab}\right)^2 ....\right]$$

I would multiply $S$ by $\,\left(\frac{ab}{1-ab}\right)\, $ and some other factor to add $I^d$ to each term in the series. However, I am not sure if this is possible.

$I > 0 $
$0<b<1 $
$0<a<\frac{1}{2} $
$0<d<1 $

Comment: No I is a constant. $I(n+1)$ equals the product of $I$ and $n+1$.

Comment: What are all these letters?  Of $a, b, c,d, I$, what type of objects are these?  Real numbers, positive real numbers, integers, positive integers, or what?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: You have not clearly defined what you mean by solve. If your asking for it to be simplified or changed, then what form do you want it in?

Comment: This question is undoubtedly related to [a previous question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279588/does-this-double-series-converge): in fact you are asking to solve explicitly a very similar series I posted as [a partial solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279588/does-this-double-series-converge/281787#281787).

Comment: One does not *solve* a sum, one *sums* it or shows it does not converge or something. But one does not solve a sum.

Comment: The series doesn't converge if $ab \geq 1/2$.

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean by find the value? Your sum is in terms of variables that have been defined with inequalities. Do you mean simplify the expression? And if you do, in what form do you want it to be simplified? Depending on the context different representations can be considered simpler in some areas and more complicated in others.

Comment: @Ethan - I want to find what the sum is equals in terms of any of the variables a,b,c,I,d.